# How can I get remote system hardware information using WMI -( Windows Management Instrumentation) from python script

Tags: python, windows, network-programming, wmi, windows-administration

**Aim**

To write a python script which fetches some hardware information of remote hosts (windows only) and I am using wmi library to connect to the remote host hardware information :

```
GPU Serial Number
Operating system version
GPU model Name
processor name
```

**My environment**

```
language - python 3
connecting remote hosts using wmi library (works)
remote hosts operating system: windows 7 or windows 10
```

**Problem**

When I run the below code, it produces 100's of classes/functions, I don't even have an idea to use it to fulfill my need (get that hardware information)

**Code**

```
import wmi
conn = wmi.WMI() 
for classes in conn.classes :
    print(classes)
```

> ```
>     ......
>     ......
>     ......
>     Win32_VideoConfiguration
>     Win32_LoggedOnUser
>     CIM_CompatibleProduct
>     Win32_PnPDevicePropertyReal64Array
>     Win32_AccountSID
>     MSFT_NetCircularDependencyDemand
>     CIM_BootOSFromFS
>     Msft_WmiProvider_GetObjectAsyncEvent_Post
>     Win32_SystemSystemDriver
>     CIM_InstIndication
>     ......
>     ......
>     ......
> ```

**Final**
How to get that hardware information of remote hosts remotely using wmi library or any other possible way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `wmi` documentation is targeted for developers and IT administrators. You need to *know* where to find appropriate classes and their desired properties. The following *commented* script could help.

```
import wmi
conn = wmi.WMI()         # or # wmi.WMI("some_other_machine")

# Operating system & OS version
for os in conn.Win32_OperatingSystem():
    print( 'OS : ' + os.Caption + ", version " + os.Version )

# Processor name
for pr in conn.Win32_Processor():
    print( 'CPU: ' + pr.Name )

# GPU model Name
# GPU Serial Number - partial solution
for vc in conn.Win32_VideoController():
    print( 'GPU: ' + vc.Name + "\r\n     " + vc.PNPDeviceID )
```

Please note that [*GPU Serial Number* **could** be extracted from `PNPDeviceID`](https://superuser.com/a/469220/376602) only if the hardware manufacturer implements it:

> Looking at the PNPDeviceID value, break it up by "\".
>
> - The first piece it the bus type. For me, it is PCI.
> - The second section describes the card. There's a vendor code, model number, etc.
> - The last section contains a number separated by ampersands. The serial number is the second number in that list, formatted in hex.

**Additional request:** monitor details like serial Number, service tag, model name.

```
import wmi
conn = wmi.WMI()

# convert uint16[] array to string
def cnvrt( tup ): 
    return ''.join( [chr( x ) if x else '' for x in tup] )

# this is 'universal' DesktopMonitor (no useful details for Generic PnP Monitor?)
for umn in conn.Win32_DesktopMonitor():
    print( 'UMn: Name             {}'.format( umn.Name ) )
    print( 'UMn: PNPDeviceID      {}'.format( umn.PNPDeviceID ) )

# this is 'specific' DesktopMonitor (all useful details?)
con2 =  wmi.WMI(namespace='root/WMI')
for mon in con2.WmiMonitorID():
    print( 'Mon: Active           {}'.format(        mon.Active ) )
    print( 'Mon: InstanceName     {}'.format(        mon.InstanceName ) )
    print( 'Mon: ManufacturerName {}'.format( cnvrt( mon.ManufacturerName ) ) )
    print( 'Mon: ProductCodeID    {}'.format( cnvrt( mon.ProductCodeID    ) ) )
    print( 'Mon: SerialNumberID   {}'.format( cnvrt( mon.SerialNumberID   ) ) )
    print( 'Mon: UserFriendlyName {}'.format( cnvrt( mon.UserFriendlyName ) ) )
```

Comment: hello JosefZ could able to extract the serial , where in windows cmd we use **wmic bios get serialnumber**

Comment: @praveen `for bi in conn.Win32_Bios(): print ( bi.SerialNumber )`

Comment: hey @JosefZ, another help! is there any possible way to extract my monitor details like(serial Number, service tag, model name). I have been searching for solution but I came back to you sir!

Comment: Answer updated. Please, (next time), ask another question instead of  extending current topic…